# SystemVerilog Sequential Circuits Coding Style

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, sequential, flip-flop

I am currently working through Pong Chu's *FPGA Prototyping By System Verilog Examples*, specifically on Chapter 4 which covers sequential circuits.  In it, Chu describes the method where a sequential circuit has the sequential part and the combinational part.  So far so good.  As an example, he shows how a DFF with synchronous clear is coded up:

```
module d_ff_sync_clr_2seg
   (
    input  logic clk,
    input  logic syn_clr,
    input  logic d,
    output logic q
   );

   // signal declaration
   logic r_reg, r_next;

   // body
   // D FF
   always_ff @(posedge clk)
      r_reg <= r_next;

   // next-state logic
   always_comb
      if (syn_clr)
         r_next = 1'b0;
      else
         r_next = d;

   // output logic
   assign q = r_reg;
endmodule
```

In the discussion, he states the `syn_clr` signal is only checked at the rising edge of the clock.  He also provides a different formatting style for the same circuit which I found clearer:

```
module d_ff_sync_clr_1seg
   (
    input  logic clk,
    input  logic syn_clr,
    input  logic d,
    output logic q
   );

   // body
   always_ff @(posedge clk)
      if (syn_clr)
         q <= 1'b0;
      else
         q <= d;
endmodule
```

In the second example (*d_ff_sync_clr_1seg*), I can clearly see that yes, at the rising edge of the clock the *always_ff* block is activated and *syn_clr* is indeed sampled.

In the first (*d_ff_sync_clr_2seg*), longer example, the statement Chu makes that *syn_clr* is only checked at the rising edge of the clock isn't as clear.  My thinking is that when *syn_clr* changes, the *always_comb* block is activated, and *r_next* is updated to be either 1'b0 or *d*.  Then, at the rising edge of the clock, *r_reg* gets assigned the value of *r_next*, as it was set in the *always_comb* block.  So indirectly it seems, *syn_clr* (or the results of checking *syn_clr*) is sampled at the rising edge of the clock.  I don't see the connection between what is going on in the *always_ff* block which is just sensitive to the rising edge of the clock and the *always_comb* which will activate whenever *syn_clr* changes.  How is *syn_clr* just sampled in at the rising edge of the clock, and hence is synchronous, if its in the *always_comb* block.

I understand that in an *always_ff* block the assignments are non-blocking and happen at the end of the block, but in this example there's only one assignment so OK.

At this point in the book Chu has mentioned FSMs and FSMDs but hasn't formally introduced those concepts in this chapter.

Perhaps I'm missing something else or my understanding of *always* blocks isn't as firm as I thought.  Any clarification would be appreciated.

Comment: The point of the first post is to show (in detail) that a synchronous reset works by using combitational logic to clock in a 0 on the d pin of a flop. This could be missed  looking at the preferred modeling style in the 2nd post. Think at the gate level and visualize a 2:1 mux in front of the d flop input. Don't loose this simple but important concept while learning details of simulation semantics, block activation etc.

Comment: I think my main issue -- and I may be overanalyzing this -- was the assertion that syn_clr is sampled at the posedge of the clock.  From what I see, it isn't.  The output of the always_comb block, r_next, is sampled at the posedge of the clock in the always_ff block but syn_clr is sampled whenever it changes, and not necessarily at the clock's rising edge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the statement Chu makes that `syn_clr` is only checked at the rising
> edge of the clock isn't as clear.

You are correct.  That statement is imprecise.  `r_next` is sampled at the posedge of `clk`, not `syn_clr`.

The 2nd code example is the proper way to model a simple DFF with synchronous clear.

It is not clear why the author chose to show the 1st example at all.

> My thinking is that when `syn_clr` changes, the `always_comb` block is
> activated

This is true, but the block is also activated when `d` changes.  More generally, the block is triggered on any change of **any signal** on the RHS of an assignment (that does not also appear on the LHS) within the block.